# How to find time stamp of last error for a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to add a monitor on a SQL Server 2012 database table which will alert me if there is an error/failure for that table. This error/failure can be for a failed `INSERT` / `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement.

If this is possible then I need a T-SQL that will give me timestamp of last error/failure for that table.

When I searched net for this I mostly found information about `try...catch` or `@@ERROR` which doesn't give me exactly what I am looking for. Another way I found was to use

```
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 6
```

But as I don't have elevated rights on DB, I get error:

> Only members of the securityadmin role can execute this stored procedure.

Is there any other way to find time stamp of last error than getting securityadmin access. If none that could be found then I'll get DBA to give me access or whatever is necessary.

Any pointers to do this are appreciated.

Comment: Talk to your DBA and get access? Or put this in a procedure with execute as and use a login that has this permission.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Sean. Do you think there is any other way to find time stamp of last error than getting securityadmin access. If none that could be found then I'll get DBA to give me access or whatever is necessary.

Comment: Well you could always try to circumvent the security and directly exec sys.xp_readerrorlog. If you open up the system procedure you called that is all it actually does. :)